# ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR in jmeter

Tags: https, jmeter, record

I'm not able to record https traffic in chrome using JMeter.

it is giving website not provided secure connection and below it is giving an error message as

> "ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR".

But only we are not able to record our website. we can able to record other https websites.

I tried of adding apachejmetertemporaryrootca.crt to browser even I'm not.

can anyone please help me, what should I do to record and did I have to ask developer team for any certificates to do this and how can I do that please help me.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is only with one website my expectation is that it will be enough to [clear your browsing history](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95589?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en), better for `All time`

[image]

[Clearing SSL State](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/clear-ssl-40339.html) is also something which can help:

[image]

Once done you should see the following warning regarding connection not being private:

[image]

This is normal as JMeter uses self-signed certificate which is not being trusted by authorities, just click `Proceed` link at the bottom and you should be able to reach your application.

Going forward be aware that you can use [Mozilla Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/) browser for recording. It has its own proxy configuration and certificates store hence there will much less possibilities for failure.

If you have to use Chrome - be aware of an alternative way of recording a JMeter test: [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-blazeMeter-chrome-extension-v4-easily-script-jmeter-and-selenium), it doesn't require any extra proxy or certificates configuration and assuming you can open the application under test in the browser you should be able to record it via JMeter Chrome Extension.

Comment: I tried all the above , and the extension which u said it is capturing the traffic but at the time of exporting it into .jmx file it is giving only one thread out of all in that ..is there any other way ?

Comment: Dmitri T , I had tried all the above u mentioned even no use , can you suggest some other way